# Upgrading From Ultegra 6600 to 6800 Help

Tags: derailleur, crankset, cassette, shifter

My Ultegra 6600 shifters need replacing. My thought was to replace it with a new 5-piece 6800 set including shifters, front derailleur, rear derailleur SS, an 11-28T cassette and obviously a new chain.

Can I keep my current compact front crank set? I just replaced the bottom bracket. 
Will the 6600 brakes work with the 6800 shifters?

Comment: Why do you think they need replacing ? In my experience the shifter rarely need replacing unless you have forced it at some point. Most times problems with shifting are due to frayed or sticky cables.

Answer (score 1):

The crank end generally is fine. Pre- and post-super SLR brakes and levers don't work together because they changed the cable pull. Presuming you have a 10-speed rear wheel, it can't take an 11-speed road cassette.